# How are fix accounts created?

Tags: fix-protocol

The fix protocol has a logon  message, but I can't find anything on how those accounts are created and verified.

Is there some other out of band mechanism for those accounts to be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It's out of band.

The way that accounts or users are managed is dependent upon the application's implementation and the organization's practices.